# what do you call a transform that is "reversible"?

Tags: terminology, transformation

for example:

- converting an X,Y,Z coordinate to Polar coordinate system
- or applying the Fourier transform and then inverse Fourier transform (or FFT)
- or in computer science, you give a utf8 string 'xyz' to encode then decode and get back the same value 'xyz'

#### what do you call a transform that is "reversible"?

Comment: These are typically called “invertible” rather than “reversible” though I’m not sure if the conversion from rectangular to polar coordinates would qualify as such.

Comment: RE rect to polar and back 'may not qualify': the question intent is still the same. perhaps my choice of examples was not the best. so maybe there are better examples. or maybe the rect to polar example should be edited out.

Answer (score 4):

Such transformations are said to be *invertible,* or to be *bijections*. If $T$ is the original transformation, then the transformation $S$ which "reverses" $T$ is called the *inverse* of $T$, and it's often denoted $T^{-1}$. The property that $S$ is an inverse of $T$ is expressed in the formal equations
$$
TS = ST = \text{identity},
$$
which says in words that doing $S$ followed by $T$, or $T$ followed by $S$, is the same thing as doing the identity transformation.